# getProperty & getSystemProperty in MonkeyRunner return None

Tags: monkeyrunner

I'm new to Android development and test, currently I'm training to make a test scripts under Python and then use monkeyrunner to run them.

As said in MonkeyDevice official documentation , the [getProperty()][1] and [getSystemProperty()][2] should return you a value that depends on property variable name you pass for them. Each time I got only 'None' value. Any idea or trick?!

The simple code I'm using :

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyDevice,MonkeyRunner

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

print device.getSystemProperty('version.sdk')
```

Regards,,,

Comment: Good, simple concise question that will help clarify the somewhat deficient and not intuitively obvious documentation. There are some other oddities in the documentation about the monkeyrunner class objects which may cause some frustration -- see my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the property group. For example:

```
print device.getSystemProperty('build.version.sdk')
```

Comment: Good, useful and concise answer. I've had getProperty('group.property') return the property requested. I've never had getSystemProperty(String property) return anything other than a None. Some Android documentation says they are synonymous but they don't seem to be. Other documentation says getSystemProperty is provided for use by platform developers which I presume to mean the Android OS and not applications. Also, build.ID and build.CPU_ABI don't work whereas build.id and build.cpu_abi do. Hope this helps the potentially frustrated developers reading the somewhat deficient documentation.

Comment: I specified the property group, and get None also. I don't know what happened

Answer (score 0):

for whatever reason both `getProperty()` and `getSystemProperty()` don't work for me but you can run:

`$ adb shell getprop`

which returns a complete list of attributes/values